# Event-Time merge of two Kafka topics using Kafka Streams DSL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am looking for a way to merge two Kafka topics based on the event time.

for example, I have two topics with the following schema `{event-key}:: {event-time-as-value}`

```
topic I -  { {1 :: 12:00pm} {2 :: 12:10pm} {3 :: 14:50pm} {4 :: 15:00pm} }
topic II - { {1 :: 13:00pm} {2 :: 13:10pm} {3 :: 15:50pm} {4 :: 16:00pm} }
```

The expected output should look like this:

```
{ {1 :: 12:00pm} {2 :: 12:10pm} {1 :: 13:00pm} {2 :: 13:10pm} {3 :: 14:50pm} {4 :: 15:00pm} {3 :: 15:50pm} {4 :: 16:00pm} }
```

Is there a way to do it using Kafka Streams DSL?

***A Note***: There is a good chance that the original topics are not ordered by event-time, and it's ok. I would like the algorithm to always pick the earliest of the two events that are currently at the head of each topic (same as the way the [merge two sorted arrays](https://javabypatel.blogspot.com/2016/10/merge-two-sorted-arrays-in-java.html) algorithm works)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kafka Streams (as of version 2.1.0) implements the exact algorithm you describe. Hence, a simple:

```java
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
builder
    .stream(Arrays.asList("firstInputTopic", "secondInputTopic"))
    .to("outputTopidName");
```

should do what you want. Note that the program will merge data on a per-partition bases.

Also consider configuration `max.task.idle.ms`.

For more details read the corresponding KIP: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-353%3A+Improve+Kafka+Streams+Timestamp+Synchronization

Additionally, you need to implement and configure a custom `TimestampExtractor` that gets the timestamp from the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the stream on multiple topics like below code:

```
val kafkaParams = Map(
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "spark-streaming-notes",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest")

val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  LocationStrategies.PreferBrokers,
  ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](Set("topic I", "topic I"), kafkaParams))
```